# netbeans can't find maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am learning maven, in one book they asked me to execute this on cmd and it works fine

> $ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple
>   -DartifactId=simple -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT

but in netbeans whe I choose "project from archetype" the build fail and it tells me this:

> Generating project in Batch mode Archetype not found in any catalog.
>   Falling back to central repository. Add a repsoitory with id
>   'archetype' in your settings.xml if archetype's repository is
>   elsewhere. The POM for
>   org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple:simple:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>
> BUILD FAILURE

Comment: could you include your pom file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the project from the command line you would have been invited to specify the archetype and version you wanted to use to create the project. Since you don't mention using any specific archetype you probably selected the default archetype which is version **1.3** of **maven-archetype-quickstart**.

Near the end of the output generated by calling `mvn` from the command line you can see the archetype you chose for creating the project:

```
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart:1.3
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: simple
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: org/sonatype/mavenbook/simple
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: simple
[INFO] Project created from Archetype in dir: C:\Users\johndoe\simple
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

However, when creating a Maven project from an archetype in NetBeans no assumption is made about the archetype you to use; you must specify it explicitly. I'm not sure what you submitted in NetBeans, but try this:

- In NetBeans: **File > New Project... > Maven > Project from Archetype**
- On the **Maven Archetype** screen search for `maven-archetype-quickstart`. I get presented with three choices in the search results, including two instances of `maven-archetype-quickstart`. Select the one with the higher version number:

[image: mvn quickstart]

- Click **Next >** to accept the options, then click **Finish** on the next screen to create the project.

Notes:

- Even if you used a different archetype to create your project from the command line the same approach is applicable. Just search for the relevant archetype in NetBeans.
- When you create a Maven project using either approach a file named **pom.xml** will be created directly under the root of your project. It is worth comparing the content of the two instances of **pom.xml** to see any differences arising from creating the project in NetBeans. If you provided the same details for both projects the two instances of **pom.xml** should be identical.